# ¿Se puede guardar en una variable un valor obtenido?

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

lo que intento hacer es guardar el valor de *values.size* en una variable llamada *id* para guardar sus datos en firebase pero cuando uso  siempre me sale null

```
    public id;                                                                       
  constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore) {
  this.afs.collection('ARTICLE').get().subscribe(values =>{
    this.id=values.size
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que se llame a la función `subscribe()` para obtener un valor debes recordar que es un proceso asíncrono, eso quiere decir que el código que hará uso del valor devuelto debe estar dentro del callback del subscribe:

```
constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore) {
      this.afs.collection('ARTICLE').get().subscribe(values =>{
        this.id = values.size;

       // aquí se debe colocar el código que hará uso de la variable id

     });
}
```